# How do I preserve identifiers while converting from HTML to Markdown with Pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I can't find the right parameter for this.

In my HTML-document I have a line like this:

```
<h2 id="seminar-teil-1">Seminar Teil 1</h2>
```

Now I want to convert this .html-document to a Markdown-Document. The end result should be:

```
## Seminar Teil 1   {#seminar-teil-1}
```

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! No wonder you were struggling. By default, identifiers are in fact preserved.

```
> pandoc -f html -t markdown
<h1 id="uid">Seminar 1</h1>
```

Output

```
Seminar 1 {#uid}
=========
```

There is one special case though, when your identified matches the identifier which pandoc automatically generates then no identifier is emitted. The automatic identifier is basically a lower case alphanumeric version of the title interspersed with dashs (exactly like your custom identifier!).

To turn this feature off run pandoc as follows

```
> pandoc -f html -t markdown-auto_identifiers
<h2 id="seminar-teil-1">Seminar Teil 1</h2>
Seminar Teil 1 {#seminar-teil-1}
```

Comment: Hey Matthew, thank you for your correct answer. I knew there had to be a parameter, couldn't find it. Now I know. I love pandoc, it's so easy to use, so fast. Just a great tool!

Comment: If you need help in future then you'll probably be better off sending a message to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) rather than posting it here. I only stumbled on this by chance but check the list every day.

Comment: Good to know. Didn't know about the group. Bookmarked it. I am sure, there are some more questions. Maybe diggin through the group will help me.